# Create contract address from the address of the creator and nonce

Tags: encoding, ethereum, solidity

I am sure that a contract address can be deterministically created using msg.sender and nonce.I read that they used RLPEncoding in python https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed/47083#47083. But I am unsure how to do that in solidity.

```
function createAddress(address creator, bytes nonce) public returns(address conractAdd) {
//SomeBody help me writing this part                                          
}
```

Comment: github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP#definition

Answer (score 0):

new contract address depends on the current address of the contract and `nonce` of the contract that you are creating based on shared link. `nonce` is counter maintained internally by a contract referring to the number of contracts
created by it but unfortunately it is not available within the contract. So you cannot create address without `nonce`.

Even though, contract creating address depends on the parent contract address and the `nonce` of the contract, there must be other variables that creates the contract address. because, if you want to create two separate contract's address in same contract. `contract address` will be same and it is likely that `nonce` of the contracts that you are creating might be same as well, because `nonce` is essentially just a scalar number. In this case you would be creating same contract addresses.

Answer (score 0):

python

```
import rlp
from hexbytes import HexBytes
from web3 import Web3
def computeContractAddress(_sender, _nonce):
    _sender = bytes.fromhex(_sender[2:])
    _address = Web3.keccak(HexBytes(rlp.encode([_sender, _nonce]))).hex()[-40:]
    return Web3.toChecksumAddress(_address)
```

Solidity

```
function computeContractAddress(address _origin, uint _nonce) external pure returns (address _address) {
    bytes memory data;
    if(_nonce == 0x00)          data = abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd6), bytes1(0x94), _origin, bytes1(0x80));
    else if(_nonce <= 0x7f)     data = abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd6), bytes1(0x94), _origin, uint8(_nonce));
    else if(_nonce <= 0xff)     data = abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd7), bytes1(0x94), _origin, bytes1(0x81), uint8(_nonce));
    else if(_nonce <= 0xffff)   data = abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd8), bytes1(0x94), _origin, bytes1(0x82), uint16(_nonce));
    else if(_nonce <= 0xffffff) data = abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd9), bytes1(0x94), _origin, bytes1(0x83), uint24(_nonce));
    else                        data = abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xda), bytes1(0x94), _origin, bytes1(0x84), uint32(_nonce));
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(data);
    assembly {
        mstore(0, hash)
        _address := mload(0)
    }
}
```